# Анимация крафта значка как в steam

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите как реализовать так, что при кнопки откр модальное окно, с анимацией желательно чтобы крутились карточки (сами карточки это div). Самое главное это анимация. Буду благодарен

Видео пример https://disk.yandex.ru/i/_VAvop7dsABeAQ

Comment: Eсли JS, то [Element.animate()], если CSS, то свойство `animation` и `@keyframes`.

Comment: Не надо ставить 100500 меток. Отмечайте только те метки, которые непосредственно относятся к вашему вопросу и внимательно читайте их описания

Answer (score 4, accepted):

± похожий вариант на CSS.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.card {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 140px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: #333;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 130%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -130%) rotate(35deg);
  opacity: 0;
  animation: Anim 4s linear forwards;
}

.card:nth-child(1) {animation-delay:   0s; z-index: 1;}
.card:nth-child(2) {animation-delay: 0.6s; z-index: 2;}
.card:nth-child(3) {animation-delay: 1.2s; z-index: 3;}
.card:nth-child(4) {animation-delay: 1.8s; z-index: 4;}
.card:nth-child(5) {animation-delay: 2.4s; z-index: 5;}
.card:nth-child(6) {animation-delay: 3.0s; z-index: 6;}

@keyframes Anim {
  0%, 90%, 100% {opacity: 0;}
  15%, 90% {opacity: 1;}

  0% {transform: translate(-50%, -130%) rotate(35deg);}
  10% {transform: translate(-50%, -125%) rotate(0deg);}
  90%, 100% {transform: translate(-50%, -125%) rotate(-360deg);}
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Можно какой нибудь привер кода?

Comment: @Prefix, что..?

Comment: @De.Minov Можешь пожалуйста всё за него сделать? :)

Comment: @EzioMercer, так и так сделал же, не? 

Comment: @De.Minov Нет, где картинки?! Где заголовки картинок?! Где надпись снизу у картинок?! Где последующий экран, где просихоит генерация иконки?? Ладно это всё шутки, ты сделал всё на ура! Всегда, когда вижу вопрос про стили жду твоего ответа!)

Comment: @EzioMercer, хох, спасибо за такие слова)